# Git issues of leaving a "deleted" file forever which can not do anything to it

Tags: git, github, version-control

One of my git repos (managed on github at https://github.com/quchunguang/test), always leave a file as "deleted" state when `git status`.

I cannot `git add` it, `git rm` it or do any other thing to remove it.
I tried `git fsck --full` but no error detected.
I deleted the entire repos and `git clone` from github, but issues still there.

This happened on my Windows 10 64-bit system, with git 64-bit (git version 2.8.0.windows.1).

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    run_myscript.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Most likely, "something" deleted `run_myscript.py`. Is the file still there when running `git status`? To get help, you'll need to provide more info, for example a complete scenario from `git clone` to `git status` reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two files, "run_myscript.py" and "run_myscript.py ", with the same contents in your repo. (The latter one has a trailing space.)

Windows filesystem ignores (removes) trailing spaces in a file name, and so probably "run_myscript.py" was overwritten by "run_myscript.py " during cloning and git is complaining that he can't find "run_myscript.py ".

You can resolve the issue by the following commands:

```
git rm "testpy/ipython/run_myscript.py "
git commit -m "Remove a duplicate of run_myscript.py."
git checkout testpy/ipython/run_myscript.py
```

Note the last checkout is needed because "run_myscript.py" (one without a trailing space) is deleted by the `git rm` from the file system somehow.

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is correct. You can’t do anything (such as `git add` or `git rm`) when the file ‘run_myscript.py’  was deleted from the working directory.

First, let’s see why it shows the deleted status when run git status. Because the file ‘run_myscript.py’ was tracked and there were some versions in the local repository.

But now, you don’t want to do version-control for the file (so you deleted it).

When use git status, it will report the information for you. Just don’t care about it when you do not need to do version-control for it any more. And when you commit for changes next time, it won’t appear.

If you are really care about the information given by git status, just use `git commit –a –m ‘info’`. You will find the working tree clean by git status.